# Locale-aware version of StrSafe function (StringCbPrintf_lW) cannot be found

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2013, strsafe

We (mistakenly) used StringCbPrintfW to write a database query which failed miserably on any locale that uses a comma as the decimal separator.  Fix is easy enough, right? StringCbPrintf_lW, which takes a locale, is also defined in strsafe.h. Both are defined under:

```
#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_APP)
```

so just create the locale and replace StringCbPrintfW  with StringCbPrintf_lW.

Intellisense is happy, GoToDefinition is happy, ClCompile is not.  I keep getting

> error C3861: 'StringCbPrintf_lW': identifier not found

Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The header Strsafe.h defines the method in question, using two defines to filter this function as follows:

```
#if defined(STRSAFE_LOCALE_FUNCTIONS) && !defined(STRSAFE_NO_CB_FUNCTIONS)
/*++

  STDAPI
  StringCbPrintf_l(
  _Out_writes_bytes_(cbDest) _Always_(_Post_z_) LPTSTR  pszDest,
  _In_ size_t  cbDest,
  _In_ _Printf_format_string_params_(2) LPCTSTR pszFormat,
  _In_ locale_t locale,
  ...
  );

  Routine Description:

  This routine is a version of StringCbPrintf that also takes a locale.
  Please see notes for StringCbPrintf above.

  --*/
#ifdef UNICODE

#pragma region Application Family
#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_APP)

#define StringCbPrintf_l    StringCbPrintf_lW
// ...
```

In short, you need to define `STRSAFE_LOCALE_FUNCTIONS` before you include the header. As in:

```
#define STRSAFE_LOCALE_FUNCTIONS
#ifdef STRSAFE_NO_CB_FUNCTIONS
#pragma message("NO CB FUNCTIONS")
#endif
#include <strsafe.h>
```

Comment: Strange quirk.  Only reason I can think of is to force programmers that spell the function name with an uppercase I (eye) instead of a lowercase l (ell) to look in the .h file :)

Comment: #define STRSAFE_LOCALE_FUNCTIONS did the trick.  Thanks.  I have no idea how I missed the missing define.

Comment: Not strictly related, but good to know anyway: *"You can define `STRSAFE_NO_CB_FUNCTIONS` or `STRSAFE_NO_CCH_FUNCTIONS`, but not both."* (from [About Strsafe.h](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647466.aspx)). Not really a surprise, but sometimes it's nice to have the obvious spelled out explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Spelunking inside the `<strsafe.h>` header, you will note that the  `StringCbPrintf_lW` function is guarded by a preprocessor `#if` like this:

> ```
> #if defined(STRSAFE_LOCALE_FUNCTIONS) && !defined(STRSAFE_NO_CB_FUNCTIONS)
> ```

So, to enable the aformentioned API in your code, you just need to have the `STRSAFE_LOCALE_FUNCTIONS` macro defined *and* the `STRSAFE_NO_CB_FUNCTIONS` macro *not* defined.

With VS2015, I noted that neither of these two macros is defined by default.
So, you just need to `#define STRSAFE_LOCALE_FUNCTIONS` before including your header:

```
#define STRSAFE_LOCALE_FUNCTIONS
#include <strsafe.h>
```

You could also define that preprocessor macro at the whole project level using the Visual Studio IDE, following: *Project Properties | Configuration Properties | C/C++ | Preprocessor* and add it to the list in *Preprocessor Definitions*.

Comment: Well, there is little point in defining the macro project-wide. It really only needs to be defined at the point of the StrSafe header's inclusion. Just put the two lines in your precompiled header and move on.

Comment: @CodyGray: Not everyone use precompiled headers in their projects.

Comment: That's true, I suppose. In that case, I'd rather create my own "wrapper" header that contained those two lines, and then include that everywhere I needed the string-manipulation functions.